# Assigning unique sources to a thread pool in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I use this [library](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool) for creating a queued pool of `pthread`. The thread is decided by the OS, but we know that we always have 4 jobs (in the below case) running simultaneously as long as the queue is full.

If each job uses one source from 4 available sources, I want to guarantee that all 4 sources are used at the same time. Avoiding a source to be used twice while another is not used in a time.

I came with this idea to use an array keeping track of used sources

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "thpool.h"

int sources[4] = {0}; // 0 Source is available 1 Source is occupied

void task(void *arg)
{
    int source;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (sources[i] == 0)
        {
            sources[i] = 1; // Occupying the source
            source = i; // Assining the source
            break;
        }
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("Thread %u working on %d with source %d\n", (int)pthread_self(), (int)arg, source);
    sources[source] = 0; // Making the source available again
}

int main()
{

    puts("Making threadpool with 4 threads");
    threadpool thpool = thpool_init(4);

    puts("Adding 40 tasks to threadpool");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        thpool_add_work(thpool, task, (void *)(uintptr_t)i);
    };

    thpool_wait(thpool);
    puts("Killing threadpool");
    thpool_destroy(thpool);

    return 0;
}
```

This works well in basic tests, but I am not sure about reliability since we have no lock on the process of updating the `sources` array.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "*we have no lock*" - it seem you already know that you need locking. Your code as shown is not thread safe and can not guarantee the constraints you want. Any semblance of it "working" is by chance and not by the design of that code.

Comment: @kaylum that was my question. I knew it was not working despite its semblance. I look for a thread-safe solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you are re-inventing the wheel, and unfortunately in the wrong way. The POSIX threads API already has the feature you're looking for: [mutexes](https://manned.org/pthread_mutex_lock.3). Simply define 4 mutexes and use those for locking/unlocking a resource.

```c
pthread_mutex_t locks[4] = {
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
};

void task(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_t *lock;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        lock = &locks[i];

        if (!pthread_mutex_trylock(lock))
            break;
    }

    // Work ...

    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);
}
```

**NOTE:** the above code only works if you always have *at most* 4 threads running simultaneously (you mention the library you are using enforces this rule so this should be fine). If you have more, the above code will simply fail to lock any mutex from the 5th thread onwards, and will then try to unlock a mutex that is locked by another thread, which is very bad. In such a case you need to wrap the `for` loop into a `while (1)` or come up with a different slightly more complicated solution like for example using conditions or semaphores.

Comment: Neat solution! Shouldn't it be `pthread_mutex_t *lock` and `lock = &locks[i]`?

Comment: @Googlebot whoops my bad, yeah `pthread_mutex_*` functions expect a pointer. Fixed. Also not sure what that `task` function signature should be, but pthreads should be `void *func(void *)`.

Comment: it's a silly question, but why do you assign individual elements instead of `pthread_mutex_t locks[4] = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER};`?

Comment: @Googlebot because `arr[N] = {x}` only initializes the first element to `x`, any non-explicitly set element will default to `0` for global or static variables, and will just stay uninitialized for local variables.

Comment: Silly of me, I was not thinking straight. I was just looking for an approach for the scalability of the code. I should assign `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` in a loop.

Comment: @Googlebot IIRC you should use `pthread_mutex_init(&locks[i], NULL);` to initialize the mutexes at runtime, as the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is meant to be used for static initialization at compile time.

Comment: by loop, I meant something like `#define THREAD 20 
pthread_mutex_t locks[THREAD]; 
add_mutex(THREAD); ` where `add_mutex` is `void add_mutex(int a){
for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
    locks[i]=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
}
}`

Comment: @Googlebot yes. That is code that runs at *runtime*, not compile time :)